# Convert julian date in Oracle SQL null

Tags: date, date-format, date-conversion, julian-date, jde

I want to convert Julian dates to normal dates (from JDE database). I run this query:

```
select to_date(to_char((DATE+1900000)),'YYYYDDD') from table ;
```

And I get the following error:

```
ORA-01848: day of year must be between 1 and 365 (366 for leap year).
```

I know it's because some dates are null or have no values.

Can anyone help me out on this please?

Comment: `to_char((DATE+1900000))` does not make any sense. What data type is the `DATE` column (and `date` is a horrible name for a date column)

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated your query and I tried with different values. Only if the date value is "0", you will get this error:

> ORA-01848: "day of year must be between 1 and 365 (366 for leap year)"

So I thought that maybe you were interested in avoid the "0" values, and you can avoid it with a simple where, like this one:

```
SELECT to_date(to_char((DATE+1900000)),'YYYYDDD') 
FROM table 
WHERE DATE != 0;
```